# Vuejs click modifiers don't work on an element inside of another element with click events

Tags: vue.js

I have a `button` with a `click="buttonMethod()"` event inside of a `card` with a `dblclick="cardMethod()"` event.

### Problem

I need to stop all the button clicks from propagating into the parent (card), but `.stop` and `.prevent` modifiers don't work, clicking on the button triggers both methods.

In the demo below, you can even see the clicks propagating from the button into the card (ripples appear)

- Using `click.stop.prevent` on the button doesn't help.
- Using `dblclick.self` on the card doesn't really help either, since it prevents clicks on all children even the text, which is undesirable.

### Code

DEMO: https://codepen.io/AlekseiHoffman/pen/LYVKeBE?editors=1011

```html
<v-card @dblclick="cardMethod()" v-ripple>
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>Description</h3>
  </div>
  <v-btn @click.stop.prevent="buttonMethod()">
    button
  </v-btn>
</v-card>
```

Comment: So you don't want the doubleclick event to affect then <v-btn>?

Comment: @Darjusch Well, I don't want any clicks on the button to propagate to the card. If you click on the button, you can see it's affecting the card (ripples appear)

Comment: @Darjusch In other words, when I click on the button it should only trigger the `buttonMethod` and when I double click anywhere on the card (except the button) it should trigger the `cardMethod`. But right now clicking on the button triggers both events

Comment: Ripples do appear, but can't see console logs printed consistently.
For example, the `cardMethod` does not gets called if I click slowly (1 click per second).
If I start clicking fast, then console logs start appearing.

Comment: Yep, `dblclick` is a double click event, it triggers only when you click twice quickly. Unfortunatelly in my real component the button closes the card, so the user might click the button quickly to close multiple cards in a row, which triggers the `cardMethod` on every 2nd click

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I just added `@dblclick.stop.prevent=""` to the button:

```html
<v-card @dblclick="cardMethod()" v-ripple>
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>Description</h3>
  </div>
  <v-btn @dblclick.stop.prevent="" @click.stop.prevent="buttonMethod()">
    button
  </v-btn>
</v-card>
```

Comment: For me this is clean than all the circus that I did ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Solution](https://codepen.io/AlekseiHoffman/pen/LYVKeBE?editors=0001)

I would take the @dblclick event out of the parent  v-card and put it only in the area that you want to be clickable.
In this case the div which contains everything beside the button.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <h1>See events in the console</h1>
    <v-card v-ripple class="card elevation-8">
      <div @dblclick="cardMethod()">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Description</h3>
      </div>
      <v-btn @click.prevent.stop="buttonMethod()" dark color="blue">
        button
      </v-btn>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but not in my real more complex component, since I cannot simply cover the whole component like in this example

Answer (score 1):

I have hack rather proper solution:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    cardMethod () {
      console.log('cardMethod')
    },
    buttonMethod () {
      console.log('buttonMethod')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.custom-card .v-card__actions { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0 }
.pb-52 { padding-bottom: 52px !important}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-card class="custom-card elevation-8" max-width="344">
          <v-card-text @dblclick="cardMethod()" v-ripple class="pb-52">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <h3>Description</h3>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn @click="buttonMethod()" dark color="blue">Button</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution. That might work for some cases